# What does selecting the Red channel in Photoshop do?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In the Channels toolbar in Photoshop, how is the selection determined when the thumbnail of the Red channel is Ctrl + clicked? I know it does something like selecting the pixels based on their R value, but I'd like to know the precise formulation behind it.

[Channels toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UIWI.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a selection as a grayscale image. For each pixel (a tiny square at a certain location), it stores a value between 0 and 255 (0: not selected, 255: fully selected).

In the colored image, each pixel has four values (between 0 and 255) for each pixel: one for Red, Green and Blue and Transparency (also called Alpha). So White pixel is 255,255,255,255, Black is 0,0,0,255, Red is 255,0,0,255 etc.

When you make a selection according a Red channel, each pixel of a selection gets the value from the Red channel in your image. So if a pixel is e.g. Red, Purple or White (all have Red=255), the selection value will be 255. If the pixel is Blue, Green, Black (all have Red=0), the selection value will be 0.

When you Ctrl+Click the main thumbnail of the layer, the Selection is made in the same way, but from the Transparency value.

Comment: Hi. I've a follow-up question. What if, say, I do one iteration of selection by Ctrl + clicking the red channel thumbnail, delete whatever has been selected and then do another iteration of the selection? What gets selected this time?

Comment: @nirisanity, what happens when you try it?

Comment: It seems to be selecting the pixels based on some combination of the Red value and the alpha value, and not just the Red value alone.

Comment: Note: [A Pixel Is Not A Little Square](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to supplement Ivan's answer.

In real life, there are infinite colors.  To deal with color in photography and computer graphics, advantage is taken of the fact that eyes can actually distinguish a "limited" number of different colors (the number is in the tens of millions, but finite).  In most situations, a subset of even that number is good enough.  For example, a photograph that doesn't contain much continuous color gradient can often be reproduced well with as few as 256 optimized colors, and tricks that fool the eye into blending adjacent pixels.

To work with color, it is represented by different "color spaces".  These either represent colors as combinations of primary colors of varying intensities (like red/green/blue or cyan/magenta/yellow), or other schemes like hue/saturation/intensity.  For any color space, the image colors are stored as incremental values for each of those color "dimensions".  With three or more "dimensions", increments on the order of 0-100 or 0-255 for each dimension yields enough total colors to be adequate to reproduce images that look good to our eyes.

If you're talking about RGB (red/grenn/blue color space), all colors are represented by a mix of those three primary colors. There is rarely a pixel of a pure primary color. Each color channel is like a grayscale image of the intensity of that primary color for all pixels in the image.  The channels are combined to display the image.

Picking a color channel just narrows what you're dealing with. The type of selection tool you use then determines what from that gets selected. Curve tools adjust the intensities just within that color channel.

Each primary color is stored separately; think of it like a data field for each primary color. So there isn't a formula to select a color channel, you just deal with a single one of the color data fields. Formulas are used to select or manipulate the values to change the appearance of the image.  Once you represent colors as values in a color space, you're dealing with numbers, and can use math formulas, formulas for mathematical curves, etc., to adjust them.

There are endless tools to select and manipulate pixels and colors in applications like Photoshop.  Each one is accomplished using mathematical formulas.